# NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported. error only in Production

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, azure

My application is running fine in localhost. However, when I deploy it to production (Azure server), I get the following error:

```
    [NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit(DbApplyExpression expression) +28
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbApplyExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +26
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +35
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +38
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +26
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree) +60
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +376
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree) +120
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +390

[EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +1479
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +73
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +149
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree) +120
   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator) +408
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +971
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +131
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +36
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +375
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   FormsCreator.Controllers.FormsCreatorController.Index(Nullable`1 id) +1044
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +108
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9987157
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

It looks like the LINQ isn't working in production, but I have no idea why.
I can't see anything wrong in my controller... Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        ViewData["PropertyID"] = id;
        var forms = db.formscreators.Where(fp => fp.PropertyID == id || fp.PropertyID == 0)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.PropertyID).GroupBy(x => x.FormName).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

        var viewModel = new ListFormsCreator();
        viewModel.Forms = forms.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.FormsCreatorID.ToString(),
            Text = a.FormName
        }).ToList();

        // Set selected
        var formID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SelectedFormId"]);
        viewModel.SelectedFormId = formID;

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I found the issue, if I change the var forms inside my controller to:

```
var forms = db.formscreators.Where(fp => fp.PropertyID).ToList();
```

It works! But I need the same query that I had before. Why the previous query did not work?

Thanks

Comment: different versions of mysql?

Comment: I use the same connectionstring in local machine and Azure which connects to another hosting provider where my MySQL is

Comment: Please see my edits in the question. It works if I change the query

Comment: It looks like the first time I connect from Azure, it works and open a PROCESS on MySQL. But, after a while the process time get too big (1000) and never closes. Then when I try to connect again it shows: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts